# There is a path but I can't get into a location

Tags: mobius-final-fantasy

I see a path to the location node, but when I tap it, "go" isn't available, it only shows "cancel". There are a few nodes that are like this, but they aren't locked and they don't have x's

Comment: Would you be able to attach a screenshot of one of these paths/nodes?  It would greatly help!

Comment: Are you adjacent to the location that you want to go to? Because to move to a space, you need to either be adjacent to it, or teleport to it.

Comment: Hah...yes. I figured out I needed to be adjacent. Thanks you both =)